# C++ - Visual Studio tries to link against symbols with @[num], but compiles symbols without that suffix

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to link against ZLib, which has been built by my solution with the same
respective configuration type as my project (Debug|Win32). When I build my main project, I get these unresolved symbols:

```
__imp__compress@16
__imp__compressBound@4
__imp__uncompress@16
```

If I had to guess, I would say that the `@[num]` is the number of bytes for the function arguments, as that seems to line up nicely. (I have tried to search what the technical term for that suffix is, in hopes to find out how I can force the compiler to export with it, but with no luck.)

Inspecting the symbols of my `zlibd.lib`, I can see all three of those symbols, except they don't have the suffix at all, nor do any other symbols in the lib.

```
6.zlibd.dll    __imp__compress
6.zlibd.dll    _compress
7.zlibd.dll    __imp__compress2
7.zlibd.dll    _compress2
8.zlibd.dll    __imp__compressBound
8.zlibd.dll    _compressBound
9.zlibd.dll    __imp__crc32
9.zlibd.dll    _crc32
```

Am I missing an option in Visual Studio to export them in that manner?

Also, I know for sure that the linker can see my `zlibd.lib`, as it shows up in every search and even says at the end that it is unused.

```
...
      Searching C:\<path-to-lib>\zlibd.lib:
...
  Unused libraries:
...
    C:\<path-to-lib>\zlibd.lib
```

If I inspect `kernel32.lib`, for example, I see the `@` in the symbols:

```
10.KERNEL32.dll    __imp__AddConsoleAliasA@12
11.KERNEL32.dll    _AddConsoleAliasW@12
11.KERNEL32.dll    __imp__AddConsoleAliasW@12
12.KERNEL32.dll    _AddDllDirectory@4
12.KERNEL32.dll    __imp__AddDllDirectory@4
```

Comment: *with the same configuration as my project (Debug|Win32* This is wrong. DLL project exporting symbols and app project importing symbols should use different compiler settings (define different macros).

Comment: When I said "same configuration", I meant that I'm using the configuration that came with the ZLib vcxproj that's labelled as `Debug|Win32`. It does not use the same macros and compiler settings as my main project. That's not to say that I'm doing it correctly, but the matter of the configuration names being the same doesn't mean the actual configs are the same in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@16` and `@4` in the unresolved symbols mean [`__stdcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-170) calling convention when you import those symbols. Missing sign `@` in `zlibd.lib` means [`__cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=msvc-170) calling convention is used while building zlib.dll. You should use the identical calling convention while exporting and importing function.

---

Since you have not provided any debugging details (build settings, a minimal example), I can only guess:

1. You use different compiler settings for the two projects: you maybe use `/Gz` in the app and `/Gd` in the dll. Use the same compiler setting.
2. You do not define the macro `ZLIB_WINAPI` in the app. Add the macro definition `-DZLIB_WINAPI=1`.
3. You define the macro `ZLIB_WINAPI` in the app. Remove the macro definition.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! It turns out that my app defined ZLIB_WINAPI, but my ZLib project did not. Defining it in ZLib fixed the problem.